# Xubuntu 14.04 does not suspend; instead it freezes and blanks the screen

Tags: xfce, power-management, suspend, xubuntu

For the past 2 weeks, ever since I've updated my kernel to `3.16.0-48-generic`, my suspend option in the `xfce4-session-logout` popup fails to work most of the times. The screen switches off, but the computer does not suspend. I can see the power light glowing as it would on while normally running my computer.

On the other hand, running `pm-suspend` as root works without any issues. What could be problem here? My machine is a Dell Latitude 3440 laptop with bumblebee and nVidia drivers installed & running.